# Variable number of nested for loops without recursion

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a list of possible permutations, but I don't think that itertools will serve my purpose. I basically need a variable number of for loops, but not sure how to go about coding this. To give a simple example (my problem isn't that simple but this example illustrates what I need), if I want all possible permutations of binary 0's or 1's with a length of 2 (01,10), I need two nested for loops. Length of 3 I would need 3 nested for loops. Any hints on how to code this when you don't know the number of for loops that are needed? Is there a way without using recursion?

Comment: If you need to state by assertion that you can't use existing tools (such as `itertools`), your problem statement probably needs to be expanded so readers understand *why*, so alternatives proposed don't stumble on the same limitations.

Comment: `itertools` is extremely powerful and flexible, it would be surprising if it couldn't solve your problem (if it is anything like your sample problem).

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say because the solution can change based on the real problem.

In your example you can do:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for case in product((0,1), repeat=2):
>>>     print case
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you underestimate the power of `itertools`.

You can use `product` in a variety of ways to mimic a nested for loop.

For example, you can use it for a single nested for loop by having 2 iterators and 2 iterables:

```
>>> for i,j in product(range(5),range(5)):
    print(i,j)


0 0
0 1
0 2
...
1 3
1 4
2 0
2 1
...
4 1
4 2
4 3
4 4
```

This is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(5):
     for j in range(5):
         print(i,j)
```

You can combine this with unpacking your list as separate arguments to deal with an unknown amount of lists:

```
>>> l = ['abc','123','789','xyz']
>>> for i in product(*l):
    for elem in i:
        print(elem,end = '')
    print()


a17x
a17y
a17z
a18x
...
b17x
...

b38z
b39x
b39y
b39z
c17x
...
c38x
c38y
c38z
c39x
c39y
c39z
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
for a in 'abc':
    for b in '123':
        for c in '789':
            for d in 'xyz':
                print(''.join((a,b,c,d)))
```

Or if you want to use the same list multiple amount of times, look at enrico's answer for how to use the `repeat` argument in `product`